# Testing interface makes sense?

Tags: tdd

I'm new to TDD, but I'm not sure why should I test an interface?

Does the code below make sense??

```
public interface IInterface
{
    int Value { get; }
}


[TestMethod]
public void Test_iinterface_value()
{
    var iinterface = mockery.NewMock<IInterface>();
    Expect.Once.On(iinterface).GetProperty("Value").Will(Return.Value(10));
    Assert.AreEqual(iinterface.Value, 10, "Doh!");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Unless I am mistaken it looks like you are creating a mock object that returns given value when asked for it. And then you ask for the value & you get it (surprise). I’d say it does not make sense to write such tests, unless you are testing the mocking framework itself or you expect the compiler to play some dirty tricks on you.

Answer (score 3):

This is known as [the Mockery TDD anti-pattern](http://agileinaflash.blogspot.com/2009/06/tdd-antipatterns.html).

However, you may want to write a set of tests that applies to all implementers of a given interface to ensure that the contracts is being properly implemented. As an example, this is what [Grensesnitt](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/10/29/hei-hei-grensesnitt/) does.

Answer (score 0):

Testing your interface mostly results in a integration test, effectively testing your whole stack. Input in the UI is processed by the application logic and by the UI response you can see "the big picture" - i.e. is your application working as expected.

In most cases, UI is composed from standard, framework-provided classes with minor alterations, so unless you have doubts in the capabilities of your UI framework, or are developing one yourself, there is no real need for unit tests on the UI classes.

If you are not using heavily customized UI classes, unit testing should not be necessary for another reason - there should be no application logic in your UI classes.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind creating a mock for an interface is to test another object (the "object under test"), which needs this mock to be created or initialized properly. Creating a mock only for testing the mock itself IMHO seems to miss the point of unit testing.

However, I can think of one case where writing a test for an interface perhaps makes sense. If you are writing unit tests not just for testing purpose only, but also for having a synopsis how to use something, then such a "test for an interface" may demonstrate how to use `IInterface`. Of course, that is more reasonable when you have a more complicated interface where its usage is not so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Testing interfaces does not make sense. Testing a mock object does not make sense either -- unless you use the mock object to test an implemented method of an abstract class (abstract in the c# definition).